# How do I add only do multiple barcharts for different months in different years

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I would like to do 5 bar charts to visually look at the different months in this 5 years to look at how each month in Year 2015,2016,2017,2018 and 2019 to see if stock X average pct_change

```
### This analysis is to see if stock X has particular months throughout 5 years which does particular better.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pylab import mpl, plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
import csv
%matplotlib inline

filename = 'xxx'

f = open(filename, 'r')

data = pd.read_csv(filename)
data.head()
data['PctChange'] = data['Adj Close'].pct_change()
data['Month'] = data['Date'].str[3:5]
data['Year'] = data['Date'].str[6:10]
results = data.groupby('Month').mean()['PctChange']*100
months = range(1,13)
plt.xticks(months)
plt.bar(months, results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/):

```
import seaborn as sns

# I am just using 2+ years for this example 
data = web.DataReader('F','yahoo',start='2018-01-01',end='2020-02-29')
data['PctChange'] = data['Adj Close'].pct_change()
data['Month'] = data['Date'].dt.month
data['Year'] = data['Date'].dt.year
results = (data.groupby(['Year','Month']).mean()['PctChange']*100).reset_index()

g = sns.FacetGrid(results,row='Year')
g.map(sns.barplot,'Month','PctChange',order=sorted(results['Month'].unique()))
```

Result (I just used 2+ years of sample data):

[image]

Comment: im getting the error of KeyError: 'Year' , below is my code

    
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
data.head()
data['PctChange'] = data['Adj Close'].pct_change()
data['Month'] = data['Date'].dt.month
data['Year'] = data['Date'].dt.year
data['Month'] = data['Month'].astype(str)
data['Year'] = data['Year'].astype(str)
results = (data.groupby('Month').mean()['PctChange']*100).reset_index()

g = sns.FacetGrid(results,row='Year')

Comment: Ok i found the answer, it is because in the result data there is no Year, thus i have to amend results to results = (data.groupby(['Year','Month']).mean()['PctChange']*100).reset_index()

Comment: @JoelChiam: I'm glad you figured it out!